# Suppressing .net's updatepanel submit event handler

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, events, updatepanel

I'm performing some custom js validation on my forms, triggered by submitting the form

```
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        var validates = true;
        // validation code goes in here
        if (!validates) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
    })
```

None of the lines I've included to stop the submit event prevent the .NET control posting back. Is there some way (using js or setting a property in the updatepanel control) of stopping post back?

Comment: Why not just set the update panel mode to conditional? Or am i missing something? (Maybe elaborate on the original problem you're having, as I don't think *this* is a good direction to proceed).

Comment: Just tried that but didn't work. What more details shodul I add to the question - I'm a front-end developer so don't really know what information to give regarding .NET

Comment: What version of .NET? 3.5? 4.0?

Comment: visual studio 2010, so presumably the latest .net version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reliable way to do this is to use the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager class:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()
    .add_initializeRequest(function (sender, args) {
        if (!function_to_check_form_is_valid(sender, args))
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to capture client click on the thing that is submitting the form.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work for keyboard users. I could do a combined click and keyup handler I suppose

Comment: And just realised that a problem with doing this is that it depends on knowing which element submits the form, and my validation code won't necessarily always have access to this information

Comment: usually the keyboard form post, submits by "clicking" the button.
How do you not know what is submitting your form?

Comment: I've just checked if the click event fires when submitting the form using keyboard (focus any element and hit "enter"), and there is no click event fired.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are doing client side validation instead of server side?  If it were me, I would just write a custom asp.net validator, then check against that validator before sending the update.  The update panel will still postback, but as long as you check against the validator, nothing will have been created.

Comment: We've been asked to do client side validation and unfortunately .NETs client side validation isn't customisable enough for what we need. We're still doing server side validation too though